# Import error when trying to use Twisted in Python

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to use Twisted in Python, however when I try to import these modules:

```
import sys
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.mail.smtp import sendmail
from twisted.python import log
```

It is finding all but the line:

```
from twisted.mail.smtp import sendmail
```

is giving the the error:

`ImportError: No module named 'twisted.mail'`

It's kind of weird because it seems that all imports are working but this is not, like the structure of Twisted was changed or something.

I'll apreciate any help.

**PD: I already installed Twisted since it is finding the rest of imports.**

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist in Python3 Twisted module but it exists in Python2 Twisted module.